# Как автоматизировать процесс создания элементов класса?

Tags: c#, массивы

Вопрос заключается в том, что после определения массива класса Player с названием plyr я определяю их значение (т.е создаю объекты класса Player).
Но этот код требует разного количества игроков. Допустим мне надо не 10 обьектов Player, а 15, но как автоматизировать этот процесс создания обьектов класса после обьявления массива?

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp6
    {
        class Program
        {
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                Player[] plyr = new Player[10];
                plyr[0] = new Player();
                plyr[1] = new Player();
                plyr[2] = new Player();
                plyr[3] = new Player();
                plyr[4] = new Player();
                plyr[5] = new Player();
                plyr[6] = new Player();
                plyr[7] = new Player();
                plyr[8] = new Player();
                plyr[9] = new Player();

                int off = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Length);
                int mur = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Length); 

                plyr[off].Mode = "Officer"; 
                Randomizer(); 

                void Randomizer(){
                    if (mur != off)
                    {
                        plyr[mur].Mode = "Murder"; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Repeat(); /
                    }
                } /
                void Repeat()
                {
                    mur = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Length);
                    Randomizer(); 
                }     



                for (int i = 0; i < plyr.Length; i++)
                {

                    plyr[i].GetInfo();

                } 


                Console.ReadKey();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Слышали про [коллекции](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.1.php)? Начните погружение с `List<Person>`

Comment: нет, маслёнок я

Comment: @AK `List<Player>`?

Comment: @Igor Ах, точно )) Пока искал ссылку - забыл о чём код ))

Comment: @AK насколько я осведомлён Листы это массивы но не с определённым количеством элементов. Или игорь спутывает мои мысли или как я понял листы это не коллекции. Ссылку можете не скидывать , оставьте это дело мне

Comment: Игорь обратил внимание, что я неправильно запомнил тип в вашем коде. List - [один из видов коллекций](https://oxozle.com/2015/04/01/kollekcii-v-net-ienumerable-iqueryable-icollection-ilist/). Собственно и массив тоже реализует интерфейс коллекции, а с технической точки зрения внутри List реализован при помощи array.  Вот вы спрашиваете как автоматизировать заполнение массива - а ведь в коде у вас есть цикл. Что мешает внутрь цикла поместить всего одну строчку инициализации очередного Player? Даже List не понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вот так, спасибо всем отвечающим на мой вопрос. Теперь познакомился с коллекциями на практике. Чувствую себя свободней в интерпретаторе.

Если не лень, можете дополнить - является ли мой код гуманным? Т.е можно ли как то сократить его или выдаёт ли мой код мою неопытность?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp6
    {
        class Program
        {
           static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int playerCount; // Переменная служит для указания количества игроков
                List<Player> plyr = new List<Player>(); // Коллекция нужна для динамичного количества игроков



                int off = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Count);
                int mur = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Count); //Ставиться случайное значения для новых переменных mur и off
                playerCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Указываем количество игроков
                for (int l = 0; l < playerCount; l++)
                {
                    plyr.Add(new Player());
                } // Цикл добавляет элемент типа Player в коллекцию plyr

                plyr[off].Mode = "Officer"; // Поле элемента из массива Player с индексом off меняется на Officer 
                Randomizer(); //Вызов функции проверки игрока на Officer

                void Randomizer(){
                    if (mur != off)
                    {
                        plyr[mur].Mode = "Murder"; // Присвоение значения полю Mode у элемента с индексом mur если это поле не имеет значение Officer
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Repeat(); // В противном случаем повторение поиска радномного значения переменной mur
                    }
                } // Сама функция проверки на Officer

                void Repeat()
                {
                    mur = rnd.Next(0, plyr.Count);
                    Randomizer(); // Вызов функции проверки
                }      // Функция присвоения случайного числа переменной mur



                for (int i = 0; i < plyr.Count; i++)
                {

                    plyr[i].GetInfo();

                } // Вывод всей информации о элементе с индексом i


                Console.ReadKey(); // Обязательно, если программа автоматически выключается. 


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Чувствую себя свободней в интерпретаторе." - осторожнее там, в интерпретаторе. Вас занесло не туда.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты имеешь ввиду инициализацию, то используй цикл, если имеешь ввиду количество, то используй список) тоесть

```
for(int i = 0; i < plyr.length;i++)
    plyr[i] = new Player();
```

Answer (score 0):

Напиши метод который тебе инициализирует плеера с нужными данными.

Допустим ты его назовешь

```
private Player PlayerGen()
{
    Player rezPlayer = new Player();

    //настраивает рандомно твоего плеера, если нужно

    return rezPlayer;
}
```

Ну а дальше в нужном месте создаешь нужное количество плееров:

```
Player[] plyr = new Player[10];

for(int i = 0; i < plyr.length; i++)
{
    plyr[i] = PlayerGen();
}
```

или вот так:

```
List<Player> players =  new List<Player>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    players.Add(new PlayerGen() );
}
```

Т.к. В шарпе List внутри реализован как Array (в других языках лист реализован как в шарпе LinkedList) то разницы между использованиями аррея или листа не будет особой. Может быть заметна разница только на ООООЧЕНЬ больших программах :) Так что по факту ты можешь использовать любой из этих вариантов и ничего это не изменит.